# Can we use type names as variable

Tags: java, android, variables, types

I've been wondering about this question for a long time :
Can we use a type name as a variable name ?

For example someone on a REST api called one of its variable "protected", is there a way to get it ? I'm developing an Android app, and the api return Json object. To accelerate the process i use the Gson library.

Comment: Every language has reserved words, those words that are required by the language to only be usable by the language, in java for example, "class", "int", "double", "protected", "private", "public" ... if I totally miss-understood the question let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Please, read this list of reserved words for Java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

But, if I remember right, in Gson you can mark variable by annotation with name of element in Gson - it can helps you.

Comment: Okay, but i can't seems to find the doc about annotation

Comment: I made little mistake. Not annotations but it possible :) https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support

Answer (score 2):

Its mentioned [in the Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) already that

> You cannot use any of the following as identifiers in your programs.

[And wiki says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords)

> programmers cannot use keywords as names for variables, methods, classes, or as any other identifier.[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords)

If still you want to use them add underscores or some extra letters to that name.

Comment: okay, i get that but what can i do with the api, i can't really parse it ?

Comment: Are you getting any exception ??

Comment: i can't build it because "Syntax error on token "protected", invalid VariableDeclarator"

Comment: The only way is to change the name there.

Comment: I found my answer, i needed to serialize the name protected to something else.

Comment: @Tsunaze Great.Something else is the only solution :)

Comment: Yes, but it's just a dumb idea to start with, to call one of its variable the same as a type, in a webservice.

Answer (score 1):

In [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> ### 3.8. Identifiers
>
> **An identifier cannot have the same spelling (Unicode character sequence) as a keyword ([§3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)), boolean literal ([§3.10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.3)), or the null literal ([§3.10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7)), or a compile-time error occurs.**

However in [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.2.2):

> #### 4.2.2. Unqualified Names
>
> Names of methods, fields, and local variables are stored as *unqualified names*. An unqualified name must not contain any of the ASCII characters `. ; [ /` (that is, period or semicolon or left square bracket or forward slash).

So

1. You can't use a type name as a variable name in the Java Language
2. You can use a type name as a variable name in `class` file.